# GLES 2.0 (LibGDX) - error 1282 on setting shader uniform

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx, shader

When I trying to change an uniform in the shader with `shader.setUniform2fv("uniform", value)`, it causing error 1282 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION). But after 2-10 seconds, it starts to work normally, sometimes... Through time, he still throws this error again.

Code:

```
shader.setUniform2fv("plyPos", new float[] {player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y}, 0, 2);
shader.setUniformf("plyAngle", player.getRotation());
```

Both these values are not null.

P.S. shader compiles without any errors and warnings.

Comment: When where are you seeing the error?  Are you manually checking GLError?  Can you include the code that does the checking?

Comment: @P.T., yeah, I'm just using printing `Gdx.gl20.glGetError()` after setting.

Comment: If you print on the line before there is no error?  I'm just double-checking because OpenGL errors will sit around until they're fetched, so it could be any statement before this one that is causing the problem.

Comment: @P.T. Ok, I solved the problem, I've put this piece of code just above...